# wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 error in using 32 bit .so in 64 bit machine using dlopen

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, shared-library

I need to use a 32-bit shared library created by somebody else in my 64-bit application in Ubuntu 14.04. I get the error given in title. I have installed libraries `lib32bz2-1.0`, `lib32ncurses5` and `lib32z1` without success. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't link an executable or shared library against a shared libraries compiled for a different architecture and/or platform. You either

1. need to get your hands on a version of the library built for the same platform and architecture either from whoever provided it to you or by compiling it from source, or
2. build the linking object for the same platform and architecture as the shared library in question. It's possible to run i386 executables on amd64 systems so that would work.

Comment: David and @Nisheet,Yes, you are right. I cannot link a 32 but .so from a 64 bit application. I thought some people had linked a 32 bit libm.so from a 64 bit application. I now have a roundabout way to do this. I have written a separate program which calls this 32 bit .so and compiled it in 32 bit. I now make a system call from my application to this separate program. The dlopen, dlsym part now is in the separate program

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you may have to enable 32 bit support.

Run following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then try installing the 32 bit libraries.

[More Info](https://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/)